# How can i strip punctuation from a string and then add it back at the same index later?

Tags: python, string, list, function, punctuation

I want the program to let's say if my word_str is "This is 'Cambridge University' for example."  It will keep the first and last letter of the word and scramble up the inside of the word if the length of the word is greater than 3 chars long.  My problem is that it shuffles words with punctuation at the beginning or end of word incorrectly.  I need it to shuffle so that the punctuation remains in the correct index and then keeps the first and last letter of the word and shuffles the inside of the word adding punctuation at the end if there is one.  Any ideas?

```
def scramble_word(word_str):
char = ".,!?';:"
import random
if len(word_str) <= 3:
    return word_str + ' '
else:
    word_str = word_str.strip(char)
    word_str = list(word_str)
    scramble = word_str[1:-1]
    random.shuffle(scramble)
    scramble = ''.join(scramble)
    word_str = ''.join(word_str)
    new_word = word_str[0] + scramble + word_str[-1]
    return new_word + ' '
```

Comment: Why not scramble just the letters while ignoring the punctuation?

Comment: Because the program specifications call for me to not ignore punctuation

Comment: But if you'd be putting it back **in the same place** as before the scramble, which in essence completely mimics the result of just ignoring it, while scrambling the alphanumeric characters. Or am I missing something?

Comment: how could i scramble and ignore punctuation and just scramble alphanumerics?

Answer (score 6):

Using regular expressions:

```
import random
import re

random.seed(1234) #remove this in production, just for replication of my results

def shuffle_word(m):
    word = m.group()
    inner = ''.join(random.sample(word[1:-1], len(word) - 2))
    return '%s%s%s' % (word[0], inner, word[-1])
    
s = """This is 'Cambridge University' for example."""

print re.sub(r'\b\w{3}\w+\b', shuffle_word, s)
```

Which prints

```
Tihs is 'Cadibrgme Uinrtvsiey' for exlampe.
```

`re.sub` allows you to pass it a function (which accepts an regex match object) instead of a replacement string.

## EDIT - without regex

```
from StringIO import StringIO

def shuffle_word(m):
    inner = ''.join(random.sample(m[1:-1], len(m) - 2))
    return '%s%s%s' % (m[0], inner, m[-1])

def scramble(text)
    sio = StringIO(text)
    accum = []
    start = None
    while sio.tell() < sio.len:
        char = sio.read(1)
        if start is None:
            if char.isalnum():
                start = sio.tell() - 1
            else:
                accum.append(char)
        elif not char.isalnum():
            end = sio.tell() - 1
            sio.seek(start)
            accum.append(shuffle_word(sio.read(end - start)))
            print accum[-1]
            start = None
    else:
        if start is not None:
            sio.seek(start)
            word = sio.read()
            if len(word) > 3:
                accum.append(shuffle_word(sio.read()))
            else:
                accum.append(word)
    
    return ''.join(accum)

s = """This is 'Cambridge University' for example."""
print scramble(s)
```

Comment: a nice solution. was going to suggest splitting the text using re.split() and re-assembling it after passing words through scramble_word but passing a function to re.sub is even more elegant.

Comment: how can you do it without re.sub?

Comment: @MikePang: Do you mean just without `re.sub` specifically, or without regular expressions in general?

Comment: without regular expressions!

Comment: I will post an update to my question addressing that, but why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: just because i'm not supposed to use them in this project, we're learning the basics still...

Comment: still nothing? i'm trying to use a for loop now and string.punctuation

Comment: @MikePang: See edit. You can also do something similar *without* using a buffer, but I'll leave you to figure that one out ;)

Answer (score 1):

Extremly easy with a regex:

```
import re
import random

s = ('Pitcairn Islands, Saint Helena, '
     'Ascension and Tristan da Cunha, '
     'Saint Kitts and Nevis, '
     'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines, Singapore')

reg = re.compile('(?<=[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]{2,}(?=[a-zA-Z])')

def ripl(m):
    g = list(m.group())
    random.shuffle(g)
    return ''.join(g)

print reg.sub(ripl,s)
```

result

```
Piictran Islands, Sanit Heelna, Asnioecsn and Tiastrn da Cunha, Sniat Ktits and Neivs, Snait Vnnceit and the Giearndens, Snoiaprge
```